# Problemas con cashier y stripe

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade, laravel-6, stripe

Deseo hacer una suscripción en modo prueba con Cashier. Tengo el siguiente código.

```
$token = request('stripeToken');

        try {

            if(\request()->has('coupon')){

                \request()->user()->newSubscription('main', \request('type'))
                    ->withCoupon(\request('coupon'))->create($token);

            }else{
                \request()->user()->newSubscription('main', \request('type'))
                    ->create($token);
            }

            return redirect(route('subscriptions.admin'))
                ->with('message', ['success', 'check', __("La suscripción se ha llevado a cabo correctamente")]);

        } catch (\Exception $exception) {

            $error = $exception->getMessage();

            return back()->with('message', ['danger', 'times', $error]);

        }
```

cuando ingreso hacer el pago me sale el siguiente error

`No such PaymentMethod: tok_1GYj7IH6LVVCiHGGM3VBo1io`

Me dicen que cashier 10 cambio su metodo de pago pero no entiendo muy bien. alguna ayuda servida de mucho. gracias.

---

Desde vue utilizo stripeCheckout y solo le paso los siguientes variables

```
computed:{
            product(){
                 return {
                    name: this.name,
                    amount: parseFloat(this.amount),
                    description: this.description
                 }

            }
        }
```

y desde la vista llamo al metodo

```
<form action="{{ route('subscriptions.process_subscription') }}" method="POST">
   @csrf

   <input
   class="form-control"
   name="coupon"
   placeholder="{{ __("¿Tienes un cupón?") }}">

   <input type="hidden" name="type" value="{{ $product['type'] }}">
   <hr>

   <stripe-form
       stripe_key="{{ env('STRIPE_KEY') }}"
       name="{{ $product['name'] }}"
       amount="{{ $product['amount'] }}"
       description={{ $product['description'] }}>
   </stripe-form>

</form>
```

Como ves en este formulario hago la petición al método processSubscription() y dentro de el esta el código que formule en la pregunta.

el identificador que me pasas no lo uso, estoy usando la ultima versión de cashier y me doy cuenta en la documentación que ha cambiado pero no he logrado entenderlo que me faltara?

Answer (score 0):

Nota: no tengo mucha experiencia con Cashier (sí con Stripe).

Debieras estar obteniendo el PaymentMethod actual desde el objeto de usuario, por ejemplo:

```
$paymentMethod = $user->defaultPaymentMethod();
```

o bien:

```
$paymentMethod = $user->findPaymentMethod($paymentMethodId);
```

Más información aquí: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/billing#retrieving-payment-methods

Si esto no funciona, algunas preguntas:

1. Qué versiones de laravel / cashier / stripe estás utilizando?
2. Puedes darnos más contexto sobre el objeto request, cómo estás creando el Payment Intent, etc?
3. Para dudas futuras, te aconsejo agregar el tag de `stripe`, así podemos responder más rápido :)

Comment: Hola gracias por responder, tal cual asi como lo escribi esta el metodo en el controlador, la peticion la hago desde un archivo js con vue.